# How to provide an access to directory outside of webapps for tomcat user?

Tags: java, tomcat7

I need to write a tomcat service to run tomcat after pc restart.
The problem is that when I run tomcat by tomcat user, resources (images, files etc) from /root/project directory is not loaded in project.
All works when I run tomcat server under the root user.

**OS:** CentOS 7

**My actions:**

```
groupadd tomcat
useradd -M -s /bin/nologin -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat
cd /opt/tomcat
chmod -R g+r conf
chmod g+x conf
chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/
```

I am using port forwarding to redirect from 443 to 8443 port in tomcat.
Only uploaded files and images are located in /root/project directory.

How can I provide an access for resources directory outside webapps (/root/project) for non-root user?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**
Do not use root home folder (/root) for non-root user (tomcat)

**You can create directory for uploaded files inside of tomcat directory, but outside webapps, e.g.:**
/opt/tomcat/project